# VS2015 XAML Designer always System.UnauthorizedAccessException

Tags: c#, xaml

I having VS2015 and experiencing XAML Designer error of System.UnauthorizedAccessException. I am running on Windows 10 build 10586.

I don't experience the error when I deleted some of the files from the Project. Once I build the project, the UWP app running and the debugger and XAML Designer start to throw error like below:

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException
Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
    at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMarkHandle stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean loadTypeFromPartialName, ObjectHandleOnStack type)
    at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean loadTypeFromPartialName)
    at System.Runtime.DesignerServices.WindowsRuntimeDesignerContext.GetType(String typeName)
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Utility.WindowsRuntimeService.WindowsRuntimeContext.GetTypeFromWindowsRuntimeDesignerContext(String name)
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Utility.WindowsRuntimeService.GetRuntimeType(String typeFullName)
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.XamlDesigner.Metadata.MockTypes.EmitContext.GetTypeFromRuntimeService(Type type)
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.XamlDesigner.Metadata.MockTypes.EmitContext.GetPlatformTypeInternal(Type type, Func`2 getPlatformType)
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.XamlDesigner.Metadata.MockTypes.EmitContext.GetPlatformTypeInternal(Type type)
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.XamlDesigner.Metadata.MockTypes.EmitContext.GetPlatformType(Type type)
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.XamlDesigner.Metadata.MockTypes.MockTypeGenerator.GetKnownType(Type type)
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.XamlDesigner.Metadata.MockTypes.MockTypeGenerator.DefineType(Type type)
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.XamlDesigner.Metadata.MockTypes.MockTypeGenerator.MockType(Type type)
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.XamlDesigner.Metadata.MockType.InitializeMockType()
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.XamlDesigner.Metadata.MockType.get_RuntimeType()
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Platform.Metadata.ProjectContextType.InitializeClass()
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Platform.Metadata.MemberCollection.get_AttachedPropertyIndex()
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Platform.Metadata.MemberCollection.CreateAttachedProperty(String propertyName, MemberKey& key)
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Platform.Metadata.MemberCollection.CreateMember(MemberType memberTypes, String memberName, MemberKey& key)
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Platform.Metadata.MemberCollection.TryGetCachedMember(MemberType memberTypes, String memberName, Boolean create, IMember& member)
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Platform.Metadata.MemberCollection.GetMember(MemberType memberTypes, String memberName, MemberAccessTypes access)
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Platform.Metadata.ProjectContextType.GetMember(MemberType memberTypes, String memberName, MemberAccessTypes access)
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Designer.UI.PropertyMerger.GetPropertiesFromSelection(IEnumerable`1 selectedSceneNodes, Boolean includeStatics)
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Designer.UI.PropertyMerger.GetMergedProperties(IEnumerable`1 selectedSceneNodes, Boolean includeStatics)
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Designer.UI.PropertyInspector.PropertyInspectorModel.GetPropertiesToShowInternal(IReadOnlyList`1 selectedObjects)
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Designer.UI.PropertyInspector.PropertyInspectorModel.GetRenderedProperties(IReadOnlyList`1 selectedObjects)
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Designer.UI.PropertyInspector.PropertyInspectorModel.UpdateOnSelectionChanged(Boolean forceUpdate, Boolean shouldCloseOpenTransactions, Boolean clearAddedProperties)
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Designer.UI.PropertyInspector.PropertyInspectorModel.UpdateSelectionCore(Boolean forceUpdate, Boolean shouldCloseOpenTransactions, Boolean clearAddedProperties)
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Designer.UI.PropertyInspector.PropertyInspectorModel.UpdateSelection(Boolean forceUpdate, Boolean shouldCloseOpenTransactions, Boolean clearAddedProperties)
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Designer.UI.PropertyInspector.PropertyInspectorModel.PropertyManager_MultiplePropertyReferencesChanged(Object sender, MultiplePropertyReferencesChangedEventArgs args)
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Designer.Properties.PropertyManager.FireAllPropertyChangedEvents(SceneUpdatePhaseEventArgs args)
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Designer.Properties.PropertyManager.SelectionManager_LateActiveSceneUpdatePhase(Object sender, SceneUpdatePhaseEventArgs args)
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Designer.ViewModel.SceneUpdatePhaseEventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, SceneUpdatePhaseEventArgs e)
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Designer.Selection.SelectionManager.FireLateActiveSceneUpdatePhase(SceneUpdatePhaseEventArgs args)
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Designer.View.SceneViewUpdateScheduleTask.UpdateLate()
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Utility.Scheduler.ScheduleTask.Update()
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Utility.Scheduler.SchedulingService.DispatchTasksAtPriority(DispatcherPriority priority)
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Utility.Scheduler.SchedulingService.DispatcherToken.Dispatch(Object arg)
    at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
    at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
    at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
    at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(Object state)
    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
    at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
    at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
    at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
    at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
    at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
    at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
    at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
    at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
    at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
    at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
    at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
    at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(DispatcherFrame frame)
    at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object ignore)
    at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)
    at System.Windows.Application.Run(Window window)
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.DesignerProcess.RunApplication()
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.DesignerProcess.DesignProcessViewProvider.AppContainerDesignerProcessRun(String[] activationContextArgs)
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.DesignerProcess.DesignProcessViewProvider.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.<applicationView_Activated>b__0()
    at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
    at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

I am not able to see the properties of the element Grid even the syntax as simple as below:

```
<Page
    x:Class="mstesting.BlankPage1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:mstesting"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    </Grid>
</Page>
```

I already enabled Developer Mode at the Windows 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update to VS2015 Update 1 definitely fixed up this issue.

Answer (score 0):

> From the error message, the user does not have the permission. You could let the application pool under a suitable account (such as LocalSystem).

Here is a [Link](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/736545b5-2de1-4cc4-a162-3789d56fcd87/xaml-windows-10-vs2015-systemunauthorizedaccessexception?forum=sharepointadmin) about this quesiton.

Comment: The link you provided is just someone who had a similar problem to me and didn't get answered.

Care to elaborate about the LocalSystem?

Comment: Yes,  a MSFT support gave this suggest about LocalSystem.  Today, I met this problem too. I used the local machine or simulator of VS2015 to debug a project, it works well, but when I used Mobile Emulator, this error occured. Turns out I should  enable Developer Mode of the Mobile Emulator too. But this error occured by me only when I want to access the info of current emulator. Can't find more info about this, sorry about this.

Comment: By the way, have you tried by running the visual studio as administrator? Right click on Visual Studio and click "Run as administrator" for that?

Comment: Yes.. I have tried with option Run as Administrator as well... No luck... I uploaded a screenshot to OneDrive. See it at: [here](http://1drv.ms/1I7Kw65).

Comment: Even though I clicked to reload the designer, the Designer reloaded successfully, but once I press one of the element and click Properties, it crashed with the same message again.

It crashed too as long as the Properties is opened.

Comment: I tried reinstall VS2015, no luck... I tried to create a project using the same source code, no luck as well... Even a blank project will have issue...

Comment: My windows 10 build is 10586.11. If everything goes wrong， will you try to reinstall windows 10? Please tell me when you solve this problem, thank you.

Comment: Well, me too on 10586.11. But I don't think this is OS issue. I think there is a bug with VS2015 when it try to get the designer properties. However, I found a workaround. I deleted some of the folder inside and it works again. I can see the properties of the element again. You can see [here](http://1drv.ms/1NrHXOJ) for what I deleted at the root folder of the project.

Comment: But as soon as I debug or build the project, it get the same error message again. This is not a pretty work around, but for now, while waiting for VS2015 first update on 30th Nov. This is working for me...

Comment: By the way, in my project, I deleted AppPackages folder, bin folder and obj folder too. Since these folders will rebuild itself when you debug or build project.